# Node based Iterable implementation in Scala

Tags: scala, iterator, nodes, iterable

Continuing my travel through exercises from Sedgwick and Wayne's Algorithms I came across one in which I have to implement a RandomBag. Originally RandomBag is supposed to implement Iterable (in java) and its Iterator had to serve items in random order.

This is the companion object of my ImmutableRandomBag:

```
object ImmutableRandomBag{
  case class Node[Item](item: Item, next: Option[Node[Item]])
  def apply[Item](maybeNode: Option[Node[Item]], size: Int): ImmutableRandomBag[Item] = new ImmutableRandomBag(maybeNode, size)
}
```

And this is beginning of the class itself:

```
class ImmutableRandomBag[Item](maybeNode: Option[Node[Item]], size: Int) extends Iterable[Item]{

      override def isEmpty: Boolean = size == 0

      def add(item: Item) = {
        ImmutableRandomBag(Some(Node(item, maybeNode)), size +1)
      }
   ...
   }
```

My understanding was that the val `size` should have overridden the def size from Iterable trait. When testing the `add` method I am getting the IndexOutOfBounException:

```
class RandomBagSpec extends BaseSpec {

  trait RandomBag{
    val begin = new ImmutableRandomBag[Connection](None, 0)
  }

  ...

  "Adding an item to empty RandomBag" should "return another bag with size 1" in new RandomBag {
    val bag = begin.add(Connection(0,1))
    bag.size should equal(1)
  }
}
```

While debugging size is correctly evaluated in the constructor parameter, so I am not sure where the IndexOutOfBoundException comes from, but I get it whenever I call the `add` method. Maybe the problem sprouts from the following. In ImmutableRandomBag there's also Iterator implementation:

```
...
override def iterator: Iterator[Item] = new RandomIterator[Item](maybeNode)

  private class RandomIterator[Item](first: Option[Node[Item]]) extends Iterator[Item]{

    first match {
      case Some(node) => random(node)
      case None =>
    }

    var current: Int = 0
    var container: Vector[Item] = Vector()

    override def hasNext: Boolean = current < ImmutableRandomBag.this.size

    override def next(): Item = {
      val item = container(current)
      current += 1
      item
    }

    def random(first: Node[Item]) = {
      @tailrec
      def randomHelper(next: Option[Node[Item]], acc: List[Item]):List[Item]= next match {
        case None => acc
        case Some(node) => randomHelper(node.next, node.item::acc)
      }

      val items = randomHelper(Some(first), List[Item]())
      container = Random.shuffle(items).toVector
    }
  }
}
```

And I have a different test in the same spec for it:

```
...
"Random Bag's iterator" should "contain all items passed to parent iterable" in new RandomBag{
    val connections = List(Connection(0,1), Connection(1,0), Connection(1,1))
    var localRB = begin
    for(c <- connections) localRB = localRB.add(c)
    assert(localRB.iterator.forall(conn=> connections.contains(conn)) == true)
  }
...
```

I also get an IndexOutOfBoundException with the following stack:

```
    [info] RandomBagSpec:
[info] Random Bag's iterator
[info] - should contain all items passed to parent iterable *** FAILED ***
[info]   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
[info]   at scala.collection.immutable.Vector.checkRangeConvert(Vector.scala:123)
[info]   at scala.collection.immutable.Vector.apply(Vector.scala:114)
[info]   at ca.vgorcinschi.algorithms1_3_34.ImmutableRandomBag$RandomIterator.next(ImmutableRandomBag.scala:31)
[info]   at scala.collection.Iterator.forall(Iterator.scala:956)
[info]   at scala.collection.Iterator.forall$(Iterator.scala:954)
[info]   at ca.vgorcinschi.algorithms1_3_34.ImmutableRandomBag$RandomIterator.forall(ImmutableRandomBag.scala:18)
[info]   at ca.vgorcinschi.algorithms1_5_19.RandomBagSpec$$anon$1.<init>(RandomBagSpec.scala:16)
[info]   at ca.vgorcinschi.algorithms1_5_19.RandomBagSpec.$anonfun$new$1(RandomBagSpec.scala:12)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf(OutcomeOf.scala:85)
[info]   at org.scalatest.OutcomeOf.outcomeOf$(OutcomeOf.scala:83)
```

The issue seems to come from calling Iterator's next method and indeed the container `Vector` doesn't contain any elements:
[image]

but why is `next` being called before `random`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> val size should have overridden the def size from Iterable trait

A `val` would have, but you don't have one; you just have a constructor parameter in  a non-`case` class. Effectively it's a `private val` and can't override anything.

> but why is next being called before random?

It isn't; in `RandomIterator`'s constructor, `random` is called (as part of `first match ...`) before the initializer `container = Vector()`. `next` is called only after constructor.

Comment: Thank you Alexey, prepending `size` with `override val` fixed the first issue. You are right random is entered before and `items` correctly gets all passed-in items, but, somehow, if highlighting `localRB.iterator` in debug mode in my test the `container` is of size 0 (basically when stepping out from constructor)?

Comment: I see now - it was overriden later by `=Vector()`. But how do I do it then? Changing the container declaration to `val container: Vector[Item] = Vector()`, moving it up before the pattern match and adding shuffled items to it with `container ++Random.shuffle(items).toVector` throws the same exception.

Comment: Woo-hoo I figured it out. I had to keep it as var but just move it before the pattern match! Thanks again!

Comment: Personally, I'd make `random` return the vector instead of modifying a `var`, then it can be `val container: Vector[Item] = first match …`.